# Root of the polynomial $x^3-x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ does not generate normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, splitting-field, normal-extension

> Show that the field generated by a root of $f(x)$ where $f(x)=x^3-x-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not normal over $\mathbb{Q}$.

First in order to mention some extension I showed $f(x)=x^3-x-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

$$\text{Theorem 1: Suppose } f(x)\in \text{F[x] such that } \deg(f)=\lbrace2,3\rbrace.  \; f(x) \text{ is irreducible over F if and only if } f(x)\text{ has no zero in F}$$

$$\text{Theorem 2: Let } f(x)  \text{be a monic polynomial in } \mathbb{Z}[x]. \text{ Suppose there exist } r\in \mathbb{Q} \text{ such that } f(r)=0 \text{. Then } r \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } r|a_0, \text{ where } a_0 \text{is constant coefficient of} f(x)$$

$$\text{Theorem 3: Suppose E is a finite extension of F. This extension is a normal extension if and only if E is is the splitting field of a polynomial } f(x)\in \text{F}$$

I have used these three theorem to prove what is asked in the question.

$\rule{22cm}{0.5mm}$

**Attemption:**

By *Theorem 1*, *Theorem 2* and $f(1)\neq0,\;f(-1)\neq 0$ we can say $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, we can construct extension field let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(x)$. It follows that $x-\alpha | f(x)$. After some calculation I left with: $$(x-\alpha)(x^2+\alpha x+(\alpha^2-1)) = f(x)\;(*)$$

Before saying $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is or is not normal extension we have investigate the quadratic factor, say $q(x)=x^2+\alpha x+(\alpha^2-1)$
. Let's calculate its $\Delta$:

$$\Delta = 4 - 3\alpha^2$$

It is clear that we have three cases. I examined case by case:

*1-)* If $\Delta = 0$. Then:
$$\alpha = \pm \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$$ But, $\left(x-\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\left(x^2+\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}}x+\dfrac{1}{3}\right) \neq f(x)$

Therefore $\Delta \neq 0$

*2-)* If $\Delta > 0$. Then:

$$\dfrac{4}{3}>\alpha^2>0$$ We can say $$x_{2,3}=\dfrac{\alpha}{2}\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{4-3\alpha^2}}{2}$$ and it is clear that $\alpha \neq \sqrt{4-3\alpha^2}$ since $\alpha \neq \pm 1$. Thus we can say $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not a splitting field of f(x). And by *Theorem 3* we can say $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not normal.

*3-)* If $\Delta < 0$. Same idea applicable. Aware that we get two complex roots. Again by *Theorem 3* we can say $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ is not normal.

All in all I conclude that the root of the polynomial does not generate normal extension over $\mathbb{Q}$

Is that right? I think it is but I am not sure the part that I use determinants? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have made the assumption that $\alpha $ is real. The algebraic way is to show probably via contradiction that $4-3\alpha^2=(p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2)^2$ can't hold for rationals $p, q, r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^3-x-1$ has only one real root, so it doesn't generate either of the complex roots.

Comment: We don't know the exact value of that real root. Because of that I said that root be called $\alpha$ and then I investigate possibilities. And my solution provide at the third part what you are saying

Comment: @beingmathematician Note the third bullet-point in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_extension#Definition